# Design survey sample with Python or R

Tags: python, r, numpy, statistics, sample

I'm trying to design sample strata for a survey (**there's no existing data yet**). I have three variables: gender, age (categorical) and education. Here are desired proportions: *(EDIT: you can find them below in the code because I created a table before but formatting didn't work)*

The total sample size is 2000. So, basically, all the variables should be crossed with each other (stratified) and next, I need both proportions and **number of people** for each strata. I tried using `samplics` library ([GitHub](https://github.com/samplics-org), [docs](https://samplics-org.github.io/samplics/)) according to docs but with no to strange results:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from samplics.sampling import SampleSize
from samplics.utils.types import SizeMethod, PopParam

# total sample size
sample_size: int = 2000

sample_wald: object = SampleSize(
    param=PopParam.prop,
    method = SizeMethod.wald,
    strat=True
)

expected_coverage: dict = {
    "woman": 0.64,
    "man": 0.36,
    "18-30": 0.20,
    "31-50": 0.50,
    "50+": 0.30,
    "lower": 0.30,
    "mid": 0.50,
    "higher": 0.20
}

sample_wald.calculate(target=expected_coverage, half_ci=0.07, pop_size=sample_size)

pprint(sample_wald.samp_size, sort_dicts=False)
pprint(sample_wald.pop_size, sort_dicts=False)
pprint(sample_wald.to_dataframe(), sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```py
{'woman': 181,
 'man': 181,
 '18-30': 126,
 '31-50': 196,
 '50+': 165,
 'lower': 165,
 'mid': 196,
 'higher': 126}

{'woman': 2000,
 'man': 2000,
 '18-30': 2000,
 '31-50': 2000,
 '50+': 2000,
 'lower': 2000,
 'mid': 2000,
 'higher': 2000}

          _param _stratum  _target  _sigma  _half_ci  _samp_size
0  PopParam.prop    woman     0.64  0.2304      0.07         181
1  PopParam.prop      man     0.36  0.2304      0.07         181
2  PopParam.prop    18-30     0.20  0.1600      0.07         126
3  PopParam.prop    31-50     0.50  0.2500      0.07         196
4  PopParam.prop      50+     0.30  0.2100      0.07         165
5  PopParam.prop    lower     0.30  0.2100      0.07         165
6  PopParam.prop      mid     0.50  0.2500      0.07         196
7  PopParam.prop   higher     0.20  0.1600      0.07         126
```

First of, all, conditions are not crossed and second of all there's no explanation where these numbers are taken from because even when I set `pop_size` to `None` I got exactly the same results. So, the results are not in any way related to n = 2000.

What I need in short:

1. Only sample design - not drawing
2. The only input is variables (**treated separately**) and their values' proportions.
3. I need to get both proportions for each combination (cells) and their counts **with the respect of total sample = 2000**).

I'm stuck. I read a lot about R (`survey`, `sampling` packages) and Python solutions to such problems but they either require existing data or I simply cannot get any satisfying results due to skill issues or library design... So, any `numpy`, `sklearn`, `samplics` or R solution would be highly appreciated!

NOTE1: As you can see my knowledge about statistics is not great...

NOTE2: I'm total beginner in R.